# How to use download files from google drive in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Where should i paste this function. I have tried millions of times but failed. Can anyone give me the full html page with this function. I have replaced with insert() on quickstart but failed. Please help me.Give me full html page.

```
function downloadFile(file, callback) {
if (file.downloadUrl) {
var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
xhr.onload = function() {
  callback(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.onerror = function() {
  callback(null);
};
xhr.send();
} else {
callback(null);
}
}
```

Comment: First things first : http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/javascript.php

Comment: then there is always F12, youre browsers debugger, look at console for errors and fix them / google them .. good luck